# Angular replace part of a string with component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I need to implement a tag system in Angular, something like in Instagram or Twitter, or anywhere.

Not sure what would be a correct approach for this.

Let's say we have a string like this: `Hello #xyz how are you doing?`.

And I want `#xyz` to be replaced with `<tag-component [input]="xyz"></tag-component>`.

So the final output would look like this `Hello <tag-component [input]="xyz"></tag-component> how are you doing?`.

And of course we can have many `#things` inside.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
 <p id="msg"></p>
```

javascript

```
function(tag: string) {
    const str = tag.slice(1); //removes # from string
    document.getElementById("msg")
    element.innerHTML = "Hello <tag-component [input]=\"xyz\"></tag-component> how are you doing?"
}
```

output

[image]

Comment: what if there will be multiple #tags?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, this: `"Hello <tag-component [input]=\"xyz\"></tag-component> how are you doing?"` is not possible because angular wont recognise the angular component tag `<tag-component>`  through innerHTML.

There could be other ways to implement this like using Custom-Directives:

Following the code for custom-directve:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[myDirective]"
})
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() tag: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.setProperty(
      this.el.nativeElement,
      "innerHTML",
      `<h1>your tage here --> ${this.tag}</h1>`
    );
  }
}
```

This you can use in your component template as: `<div myDirective tag="test"></div>`to render your expected tag.